# Custom OAuth server not firing the openid-configuration endpoint in .NET 7

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth, .net-7.0

I am following this tutorial:

https://dev.to/mohammedahmed/build-your-own-oauth-20-server-and-openid-connect-provider-in-aspnet-core-60-1g1m

to implement a custom `OAuth authentication server`.
I created in a test `solution` the two `MVC projects` of which one is the client and the other is the OAuth server.

Following the tutorial I added `AddOpenIdConnect` in the `Program.cs` of the project with the configurations for communication with the OAuth server:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(config =>
{
     config.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     config.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
  .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
  {
      // this is my Authorization Server Port
      options.Authority = "https://localhost:7250";
      options.ClientId = "platformnet7";
      options.ClientSecret = "123456789";
      options.ResponseType = "code";
      options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
      options.SaveTokens = true;
      options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
      {
          ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
          SignatureValidator = delegate (string token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
          {
              var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(token);
              return jwt;
          },
      };
  });
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();

app.Run();
```

Whereas these are the `Program.cs` and the controller in the OAuth server:

```cs
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication();
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Accounts/Login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Accounts/AccessDenied";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
});

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();

app.Run();
```

```cs
[HttpGet(".well-known/openid-configuration")]
// [HttpGet("~/.well-known/openid-configuration")] both are not working
public JsonResult GetConfiguration()
{
    DiscoveryResponse response = new()
    {
        issuer = "https://localhost:7250",
        authorization_endpoint = "https://localhost:7250/Home/Authorize",
        token_endpoint = "https://localhost:7250/Home/Token",
        token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported = new string[] { "client_secret_basic", "private_key_jwt" },
        token_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported = new string[] { "RS256", "ES256" },

        acr_values_supported = new string[] { "urn:mace:incommon:iap:silver", "urn:mace:incommon:iap:bronze" },
        response_types_supported = new string[] { "code", "code id_token", "id_token", "token id_token" },
        subject_types_supported = new string[] { "public", "pairwise" },

        userinfo_encryption_enc_values_supported = new string[] { "A128CBC-HS256", "A128GCM" },
        id_token_signing_alg_values_supported = new string[] { "RS256", "ES256", "HS256" },
        id_token_encryption_alg_values_supported = new string[] { "RSA1_5", "A128KW" },
        id_token_encryption_enc_values_supported = new string[] { "A128CBC-HS256", "A128GCM" },
        request_object_signing_alg_values_supported = new string[] { "none", "RS256", "ES256" },
        display_values_supported = new string[] { "page", "popup" },
        claim_types_supported = new string[] { "normal", "distributed" },

        scopes_supported = new string[] { "openid", "profile", "email", "address", "phone", "offline_access" },
        claims_supported = new string[] { "sub", "iss", "auth_time", "acr", "name", "given_name",
            "family_name", "nickname", "profile", "picture", "website", "email", "email_verified",
            "locale", "zoneinfo" },
        claims_parameter_supported = true,
        service_documentation = "https://localhost:7250/connect/service_documentation.html",
        ui_locales_supported = new string[] { "en-US", "en-GB", "en-CA", "fr-FR", "fr-CA" }
    };

    return Json(response);
}
```

At this point the tutorial states that by running both projects (first the server and then the client), during startup the client should immediately call my `.well-known/openid-configuration` endpoint, but in fact when I start the applications nothing happens and from the client su
`Chrome` `DevTools` in the `Network` tab I see that no calls are made at all, not even that it fails.

This is pretty much the beginning of the tutorial by the way, so I really don't know what I could be doing wrong. I also checked the `7250` port is the correct one of the server and from the launcSettings.json it seems to me the correct one (I use the `https` profile, both the projects use the https profile):

```json
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57997",
      "sslPort": 44326
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5087",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7250;http://localhost:5087",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also put the client launchsetting for completeness:

```json
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:54947",
      "sslPort": 44377
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5174",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7077;http://localhost:5174",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the main difference is that my projects are in `.NET 7` and the tutorial is on `.NET 6` projects, but I don't know if the problem comes from that.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I forgot to decorate the Client controller with the `Authorize` attribute.
By adding it the client started communicating with the `OAuth server`.